# Javascript onckick no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Tengo un problema con mi sitio en wordpress. La cosa es que quiero implementar código para un botón y encapsularlo en un archivo JS, pero soy incapaz de que al pulsar el botón salte dicha función.

Ahora mismo esta así:

PHP:

```
function my_favicon_link()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('cambiar_precios',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/cambiar_precios.js', 
     array('jquery'), '', false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_favicon_link' );
```

Este código funciona sin problemas, ya que dando al inspeccionar código fuente de la pagina, se encuentra que lo esta importando bien y apunta al archivo correcto.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(document).on("click", "#button_prices", function () {  
        alert('hola');
    });
    
    $('.#button_prices').click(function(){
        alert('hola');
    });
});
```

Aquí, si pongo el alert antes del ready si se muestra, pero si no nada.

No se que estoy haciendo mal la verdad, estoy un poco perdido sobre este tema.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cambia el simbolo `$` por `jQuery`, de esta forma `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` esto para evitar problemas con jQuery.
2. En el selector esta dando un `.` como parte del  selector, `.#button_prices remuevalo => #button_prices`
3. Verifica que el ID del botón sea correcto